# How to Write to a file and then read the file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have written the following code:

```
supported = open("Mails/mymails.txt",'w')
with open("emails.txt","r") as handle:
    for line in handle:
        if line.strip():
            list = line.split(":")
            email = list[0]
            domain = email.split("@")
            if domain[1] in blacklist:
                blacklisted = blacklisted+1
            if domain[1] in dictionary and domain[1] not in blacklist:
                valid=valid+1
                supported.write(domain[1])
            
    print(valid,blacklisted)
with open("Mails/mymails.txt",'r') as handle1:

    for line1 in handle1:
        print(line1)
```

I used append mode and it worked fine, but when i use multiple files, i have to manually delete supported.txt file to make sure the new file lines are not appended to old file lines
Any help is appreciated

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're expecting here, and if using `.close()` was the solution, well surely you should have been using a `with` statement on the supported file anyways

Answer (score 0):

I closed the file and it worked fine

like : `supported.close()` at the end of first `with` statement